# google apps script how to protect a range from oneself

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have tried to make a google app script in Google Spreadsheet that will protect a range from the user who is running the script. The need is that a user of this script should not be able to edit a certain range after running the script. Another user (the supervisor) will be informed that the user has (locked) this range ready to be accepted by the supervisor.

I've tried this:

```
var protection = ss.getRange(start_row,start_col,30,7).protect().setDescription('Suunnitelma ilmoitettu.');
ss.getRange(start_row,start_col,30,7).protect().removeEditor(Session.getEffectiveUser());
```

However, it doesn't work. The current user has always permission for the range. Is it possible to protect a certain range of google apps script from oneself and leave it unprotected only for the owner?

Comment: I also tried this as replacing Session.getEffectiveUser() with a google account in email-format ie. user@gmail.com, but with no luck either.

Comment: You'll need to write code that can be called from your sheet and runs an outside code bit (e.g. a script published as a web app). Your webapp would then open the requesting spreadsheet (supply an id in the request), and then apply a protection to the given range (provide the range in the request), that prevents the user (supply the user email in the request) from modifying it. The webapp will have to run as someone who has the authority to edit the requesting workbook, and is not the user who is making the request.